# How to have console output for Intel ManyCore Lab batch jobs?

Tags: batch-file, openmp, intel, jobs, qsub

I'm currently testing an OpenMP parallel program on Intel's ManyCore Testing Lab computers, and have been using

```
qsub -l select=1:ncpus=30 $HOME/myjob
```

to add the job and run it. It puts the output from the program into a file called myjob.o123456 (where the numbers depend on the job ID), but I'd like it to output to the console while the job is running, that way I can figure out the progress my program is making. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Interactive Jobs in torque.

http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/help.htm#topics/commands/qsub.htm#-I

Basically just add a -I to get an interactive shell on the node.

qsub -I -l select=1:ncpus=30 $HOME/myjob

Note: If you are using torque 4.x, make sure you are using torque 4.2.2 or 4.1.5.1 or later because there was recently a bug with interactive MPI jobs.